# Методом гаусса найти обратную матрицу

Tags: python, матрицы

Саму матрицу составил, но как методом гаусса найти обратную вообще не понимаю.

```
row = int(input('Введите величину строк матрицы:'))
column = int(input('Введите величину столбцов матрицы:'))
m = row
matrix = []
a = []
print("Введите элементы матрицы:")
for i in range(row):
    s = input().split()
    for j in range(column):
        a = list(map(int, s))
    matrix.append(a)


def build_array(n):
    return [[1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(0,row):
    matrix[i].extend(build_array(row)[i])
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уточните - вы не прочитали про метод Гаусса, или про то, как с его помощью найти обратную матрицу?